# ElasticSearch GeoDistance Query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

I am using geodistance query in python like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "20miles",
          "location": {
            "lat": 51.512497,
            "lon": -0.052098
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is working correctly. My problem is how to give "distance" a value from within the document. I have a field like this `distance: 50` in my index for each record and I want to use it as a value of distance in geodistance. I tried `"distance":doc['distance'].value` but it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordinary queries and filters are not expecting scripts to be placed within them.

Assuming that you have stored a `geo_point` with the field name of `location`, then you want to use a [script filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html) using the [doc['field_name'].distanceInMiles(lat, lon)](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_document_fields) (as opposed to `distance(lat, lon)` because the standard units are `meters` as-of `v1.0.0`):

```
{
  "filtered" : {
    "query" : { "match_all" : { } },
    "filter" : {
      "script" : {
        "script" :
          "doc['location'].distanceInMiles(lat, lon) < doc['distance'].value",
        "params" : {
          "lat" : 51.512497,
          "lon" : -0.052098
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*If you are running an instance of Elasticsearch where it is using the previously standard units of `miles`* (pre-`v1.0.0`), then you can use the plain `distance` function (or if your units for `distance` already happened to be in the now-standard `meters` as-of [`v1.0.0`](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/commit/464037e0c18d5bbcc33db0e01acde6c8849324a9)):

```
{
  "filtered" : {
    "query" : { "match_all" : { } },
    "filter" : {
      "script" : {
        "script" :
          "doc['location'].distance(lat, lon) < doc['distance'].value",
        "params" : {
          "lat" : 51.512497,
          "lon" : -0.052098
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: you could supply the values of `lat` and `lon` directly within the script for one-off execution, but scripts are compiled *and* cached, so using parameters allows reuse and therefore faster execution after the first use.

As noted in the documentation, you can cache the result of the filter by adding `"_cache" : true` to the filter, but the result of the filter is *not* cached by default.

Comment: I tried it but got the following error "  query[filtered(ConstantScore(ScriptFilter(doc['location'].distanceInMiles(lat, lon))))->cache(_type:users-schema)],from[0],size[10]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: PropertyAccessException[[Error: unable to resolve method: org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$GeoPoints.distanceInMiles(java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double) [arglength=2]] [Near : {... doc['location'].distanceInMile ....}] ^ [Line: 1, Column: 1]]; }]"

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using? That method was added in [`v1.0.0`  in late December, 2013](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/commit/464037e0c18d5bbcc33db0e01acde6c8849324a9). Fortunately though, prior to 1.0, the default units were `miles` already (as opposed to `meters`), so you can change the method to `distance(lat, lon)` from `distanceInMiles(lat, lon)` and it should work the same.